# _trigger not working inside Bind - Jquery widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-widgets

I am working on a jQuery widget for one of my counter plugins. I just started to learn this plugin coding and I'm stuck at the point where i have to use trigger to call event with in _create to access public function 'tickup'. When i tried with the following code it is not working , I am binding click event to some buttons having attributes data-step. and once we click this buttons , it should fire function 'tickup' int he widget.

```
_create: function() {
    var self = this;
    var tickObj = self.element.find('[data-step*="tick-"]');

    tickObj.bind("click", function(e) {
        self._trigger('tickup', null, {});
    });
},

tickup: function() {
    alert('tickup');
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -2):

```
_create: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.bind('tickup' function() {
        alert('tickup');
    });

    var tickObj = self.element.find('[data-step*="tick-"]');

    tickObj.bind("click", function(e) {
        self._trigger('tickup', null, {});
    });
})
```

Comment: why you binded tickup in the _create , i wanted it to be public function ??? how can i create tickup be public function ???